# Using "userNotificationCenter willPresent notification: UNNotification" slow extremely my computer

Tags: swift, sourcekitservice

When using `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)`
in AppDelegate, Sourcekitservice and swift spending
a lot of memory(40GB to 50Gb), RAM and CPU(over 90%) right after this method had been adding(no need to build or run) . Anyone has the same issue or can explain this for me.
I'm using Xcode 11.3.1 and macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Thanks in advance.